# Lasagne / Theano gradient values

Tags: python, theano, lasagne

I'm currently working on recurrent neural nets using Lasagne / Theano.

While training, updates are calculated using Theano's symbolic gradient.

```
grads = theano.grad(loss_or_grads, params)
```

While the gradient *expression* is perfectly fine in general, I'm also interested in the gradient *values* in order to monitor training.

My question now is if there is a built-in method to also get gradient values, which I haven't found so far, or if I'll have to do it myself.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not aware of any lasagne function to evaluate the gradient, but you can get it yourself with simple theano function.

Say we have the following theano variables:

- `inputs` = Inputs to the network
- `targets` = Target outputs of the network
- `loss` = Value of the loss function, defined as a function of network outputs and `targets`
- `l_hid` = Recurrent layer of the network, type `lasagne.layers.RecurrentLayer`

Say we're interested in the gradient of the loss function w.r.t. the recurrent weights:

```
grad = theano.grad(loss, l_hid.W_hid_to_hid)
```

Define a theano function to get a numerical value for the gradient

```
get_grad = theano.function([inputs, targets], grad)
```

Now, just call `get_grad` for any value of the inputs and targets (e.g. the current minibatch). `get_grad()` doesn't need to be passed the value of the weights because they're stored as a theano shared variable.